# DataTable PrimeFaces columns width not changes

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

Is there any way to specifie the same `width` of columns in datatable, for example this part of my `dataTable`, but the width is not equal for all the columns :

```
<p:dataTable value="" styleClass="hide-content-names">
    <p:columns value="#{managedBean.listObject}" 
               var="head" headerText="#{head.code}" width="20px;"/>
</p:dataTable>
```

[image: Width of columns]

Is there any solution for that?

Thank you.

Comment: try to make this `style="width: 20px"` instead of `width`

Comment: Thank you @YagamiLight, I do that before but same result

Comment: does your `dataTable` inside a `form` ?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this is to write some custom CSS. If you don't want to apply this to all your data tables add a class to your data table, let's say `my-table`.

By default PrimeFaces data tables are set to `width: 100%`. Override that first to `auto`:

```
.my-table.ui-datatable table { width: auto; }
```

Now, instead of `width`, set the `max-width` to `20px` for both `th` and `td` in your table:

```
.my-table.ui-datatable th, .my-table.ui-datatable td { max-width: 20px; }
```

Using the `style` attribute on your column for this will also work.